# How to do dynamic regex group capturing after text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:
`@e[scores={score_1=19,score_2=14,score_3=14..}]`

I would like to capture the names of the scores in `scores={}` there could be an unlimited amount of them. These strings however can also look like this:

`@e[distance=..10,scores={score_1=19,score_2=14,score_3=14..},tag=hi,limit=10]`

So only the score names inside scores should be captured and all in separate groups.

So my ideal output would be: `["score_1", "score_2", "score_3"]`

I came up with a sort of solution for this problem: `scores={(?:(\w+)=[.\d]*)(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?` and then the idea is to repeat `(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?` to capture more scores. This is bad because it is not dynamic and it would put a limit on how many scores can be detected. Also if I would repeat `(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?` lets say 4 times and only 1 score is found like this:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"scores={(?:(\w+)=[.\d]*)(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?(?:,(\w+)=[.\d]*)?")
result = re.findall(pattern,"@e[scores={score_1=19,score_2=14}]]\n@e[scores={score_1=19,score_2=14}]]")
print(result)
```

This gives: `[('score_1', 'score_2', '', '', ''), ('score_1', 'score_2', '', '', '')]`
So all the groups that did not find anything are just empty strings. This is kind of inconvinient because all my other regexes only have 1 capture group.

So there any better way to do this? The problem is that I first need to detect if an argument is in the `scores={}` but then it should dynamically catch the groups inside the `scores={}` and if possible only return a list with the found matches.

Comment: When there are multiple sets of scores should the result be similar to: `[('score_1', 'score_2',), ('score_1', 'score_2')]` i.e. list of tuples where each tuple is from a set?  Also is there always a `\n` delimiter between sets of scores?

Comment: You could do it in multiple steps, capture what is between the curly braces and then split on `,` and split those values again on `=` taking the first part.

Comment: All my other regexes that find things in the text all only work with one capture group this means that all of those do just return a list with the found items instead of a list with tuples. It would be better for my flow if the groups items are always returned in a list with a tuple. This is also why I don't really want to split because all the other regex I have I don't have to split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *PCRE* regex engine I would suggest to use a regex pattern

```
(?:^@\w+\[[^{]+{|\G(?!\s*$))([^=]+)=[^,}]+(?:,|}.*$)
```

and store all ***Group 1*** matches.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/TiXPoy/2).

---

However, since *Phyton* doesn't support `\G`, you would have to use an emulation technique:

```
pattern = '(?:^@\w+\[[^{]+{|(?!\s*$))([^=]+)=[^,}]+(?:,|}.*$)'

matcher = re.compile(pattern)

index = 0
m = matcher.match(s, index)
o = []

while m and index != m.end():
    o.append(m.group(1))
    index = m.end()
    m = matcher.match(s, index)
```

See this [Phyton demo](https://www.ideone.com/4LqXVK).